# How to build a 1D CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use a CNN for classification. My training data is shown in the picture below and has 9923 pieces of data with each piece containing 1k numeric values. [image]

My current model has only around 10 percent accuracy and I am wondering if anyone knows if I am doing something wrong.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64,3, activation ='relu', input_shape= (1000, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Conv1D(64,3, activation ='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(28, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs = 30, validation_split = 0.1)
```

Comment: What is the range of Y values?

Comment: The range of Y values is just (9923,) labels

Comment: Not the size, I was asking about the values of Y. What is your output for each example, like Y = 2, Y = 1, Y = 6, whats the max and min values of output

Comment: Oh sorry, the outputs are numbers from 1-24

Comment: Since you have 24 outputs, you should use 24 neurons in last layer (output one). You are getting just 10% accuracy, I could infer that you are not using one hot encoding for Y (maybe I am wrong), as softmax will output values from 0 to 1, but your Y has values from 1-24. Check for one hot encoding.

Comment: So I should divide all the Y values by 25 to get them between 0 and 1?

Comment: No, the output of last layer will be a array of 24*1 with all values between 0 and 1. The maximum of those values will be your prediction of the model. So to evaluate loss, your Y should be also array of 24*1 for each input ( if y = 12 then Y[11,1] = 1 and all other values will be zero). So use one hot encoding (you could easily get on internet). So, dividing by 25 won't work here. Also, I think you should evaluate loss as 'categorical_crossentropy'

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you for your help.